# Issues with implementing a custom controller in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Basically I have to generate PDF of wishlist items(products) using the chunk of codes as specified in http://gorrc.blogspot.in/2012/05/magento-print-whishlist-to-pdf.html.
Now the problem is, I am not able to trace out where and how to call all the methods as  specified in above link. Can anyone help me in this or provide any alternate solution, I mean some other ways for generating PDF of wishlist items. Any Help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

How you want to do it?
Say more about where you want do this action and i'll point the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I have to generate PDF of wishlist items(products) which contains only images of products in magento. However the solution specified in gorrc.blogspot.in/2012/05/magento-print-whishlist-to-pdf.html doesn't mention where to call all the methods in it. I want steps for where to create controller and how to call its methods(functions) in phtml file. I think it would be better if you provide me some other ways for generating PDF of wishlist items. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is controller, its end point of url request.
Method is called when you navigate to specified URL.